# ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars when converting list to float Torch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have the following:

```
type of X is:  <class 'list'>
X: [tensor([[1.3373, 0.5666, 0.2337,  ..., 0.4899, 0.1876, 0.5892],
        [0.0320, 0.0797, 0.0052,  ..., 0.3405, 0.0000, 0.0390],
        [0.1305, 0.1281, 0.0021,  ..., 0.6454, 0.1964, 0.0493],
        ...,
        [0.2635, 0.0237, 0.0000,  ..., 0.6635, 0.1376, 0.2988],
        [0.0241, 0.5464, 0.1263,  ..., 0.5766, 0.2352, 0.0140],
        [0.1740, 0.1664, 0.0057,  ..., 0.6056, 0.1020, 1.1573]],
       device='cuda:0')]
```

However, following the instructions in [this video](https://www.aiworkbox.com/lessons/convert-list-to-pytorch-tensor), I get this error:

```
    X_tensor = torch.FloatTensor(X)
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

I have the following conversion code:

```
X_tensor = torch.FloatTensor(X)
```

How can I fix this problem?

```
$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.__version__
'1.10.1+cu113'
```

X here is a list of torch.tensors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `torch.stack()`:

```
X = torch.stack(X)
```